# How to speicify list inside map in spring boot application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I need to have list of POJO(ServiceMetadata) inside a map, which will read configuration
from application.properties

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "props")
@Data
@Component
public class ApplicationConfig {
    private Map<String, List<ServiceMetadata>> markets = new HashMap<>();
}


@Data
public class ServiceMetadata {

    private String applicationName;
    private String backendURL;
}
```

I tried the below, it is not working.

props.markets.UK.serviceEndpoints[0].applicationName=abc
props.markets.UK.serviceEndpoints[1].backendURL=http://localhost:8080/api/v1/markets/{marketId}
props.markets.ES.serviceEndpoints[0].applicationName=xyz
props.markets.ES.serviceEndpoints[1].backendURL=http://localhost:8080/api/v2/markets/{marketId}

Comment: in this case, our project create an singleton bean to read properties file and store the value to reuse.

Comment: Have you tried `props.markets.UK[0].applicationName=abc` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try bellow:

```
props.markets.UK[0].applicationName=abc
props.markets.UK[0].backendURL=http://localhost:8080/api/v1/markets/{marketId}
props.markets.UK[1].applicationName=def
props.markets.UK[1].backendURL=http://localhost:8080/api/v1/markets/{marketId}
props.markets.ES[0].applicationName=xyz
props.markets.ES[0].backendURL=http://localhost:8080/api/v2/markets/{marketId}
```